# ubuntu - ldconfig is missing from filesystem after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have upgraded Ubuntu server from 15.10 to 16.04 and after that the ldconfig has been removed from the system (I can't find in system and in any possible path, /usr/sbin, /sbin).

As a result can't proceed with further upgrade due to
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 4):

```
apt-get download libc-bin
dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb unpackdir/
```

Next you need to copy these files:

```
sudo cp unpackdir/sbin/ldconfig /sbin/
```